# Magento 2 command line for php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, theme

I have an issue to install Magento theme extension using -jailshell-4.2$

I used to be use command line php bin/magento setup:upgrade

And now the "TERMINAL" on my mac doesn't work properly as before.

[image]

Does anyone know what command line should I typing?

Thank you

Comment: 'sudo rm -rf var/cache/* var/di/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/*'
    'sudo rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/*'
    'sudo chmod -R 0777 pub var generated' run these command and then try yours

Answer (score 1):

1. Clear cache and delete generated folder then try again.
2. Check if you have magento file in bin directory
3. If vendor folder is not in .gitignore file then check if some file
   are missing from core by 'git status'.
4. You can download the folder manually and place it in root folder of
   magento then can use setup:upgrade, static-content:deploy,
   cache:clear, cache:flush.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
php ./public_html/bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to move in your project root folder first.

In my case that is `/var/www/html`. It can't find command because you are not pointing to it by `bin/magento`, you need to tell it where magento is. So in my case`/var/www/html/bin/magento`.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this step to run Magento 2 cli command

```
$ cd public_html
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: For example my project on "public_html/abc.com/
then write "cd public_html/abc.com/"

Answer (score 0):

Check permission first and ownership.

> make sure you are on the project root folder or inside bin/magento (remove bin/magento form commands than)

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data  -R *
sudo rm -rf var/ 
sudo rm -rf pub/static
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to run:

```
composer install
```

In the root magento folder